# React-Native Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

When I going to run my react native app on my iPhone Expo this error displayed in red background area.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

this is the App.js inside the 'src/components/' folder

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the main App.js in react-native app folder.

```js
import App from './src/components/App';
```

I used expo app for run this code. How can I solve this error?

Comment: How do you know problem is about the App.js file?

Comment: I don’t know about that also i didn’t mentioned that app.js has errors. I need to get a idea about this problem and how to solve this.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you shared. I just built a test app with that and it works. Can you share the rest of the app code? Or a sample app? If possible, put it in github.

Comment: this is simple app I tried to study. these are the codes which i made changes. others are react native bundle of codes. i didn't change anything from that.

Comment: export default App;
or
export  {LoginForm};

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expo expects you to export a component from `/App.js`. But right now you are only importing into `/App.js`. Expo is not receiving any component to render. You need to export the component you imported like this:

```
export default App;
```

*On side note:* Use a class component only if you must.

Comment: Did you add the export to the main App.js or to the component? You need to add it to the main file.

Answer (score 7):

In my case instead of exporting like this:

```
export default App;
```

...I exported like following:

```
export {LoginForm};
```

It worked completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error from doing my export in the following style with no default export specified. I did not specify a default because I was exporting multiple small components from one file.

```
export const  Modal  = (props) => (
    <div className="someClass">
    </div>        
  )
```

I was able to get it working by adding brackets to the import statement.

```
import {Modal} from '../components/Modal.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue and i put 
`export default` 
before 
`class yourclassname extends Component` 
in App.js

Comment: Add some more details

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, I had exactly this issue and it had me stumped for 2 days. My mistake was creating and renaming some files — stupidly, whilst my project was still running. This inadvertently messed up some of my paths/imports. I wasn’t seeing any issues in VS Code however every time I ran the project it would work first time after a full clean and then when I refreshed I’d get this error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication).
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

I only knew this was the issue because I got my colleague to sync the project using my branch and test it on his Mac and it worked fine. The solution might be to try cleaning Android, iOS and Watchman first and if that doesn’t work I would suggest try deleting the project folder from your machine and re-clone the repo and run it again.

Useful clean scripts to try:

For Android:

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && yarn cache clean && yarn && cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd ..
```

For iOS:

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && rm -rf ios/build && yarn cache clean && yarn && cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd ..
```