# React-native app after crash show splash screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native

There was a situation, that with some crashes, the application does not close as usual, but shows splash screen. The behavior is the same on both Android and iOS. This situation occurs when the fall occurs with an error invariant violation. I do not know what to do with such a problem, what is the issue?

Comment: **You can check this answer** :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825540/react-native-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid?rq=1

Comment: my problem is not to correct the error of invariant violation
I did this a long time ago. The problem is, why the application does not close, but it remains to show splash screen

Answer (score 0):

as in your navigation, the back button plays the go back function and in your navigation splash screen is the previous screen so it is doing.

if you want to close the app then use the `Backhandler.exitApp()` for closing the app from which screen you want to close